# Creating an Android Activity of just a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-activity, progressdialog

I have an Activity that runs an AsyncTask on a TimerTask. While the task is being run, I show a ProgressDialog, and fire an intent to open another Activity when complete.

I would like to only show a ProgressDialog when this occurs, but if I leave out setContentView, my app still creates a small window display for the Activity. Is it possible to just show the ProgressDialog?

I could put the code from this Activity into the parent Activity that calls it but I want to be able to reuse this code, calling it from other Activities when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that creating an Activity just for displaying a dialog isn't the best approach. Dialog views are typically mean't to be displayed on top of the current activity. If an Activity only contained a dialog and nothing else, then it would simply be a dialog window floating over an empty black background, which wouldn't be the best design idea.

If you want a reusable dialog, I would suggest making a standalone class that wraps the dialog in question. Then instantiate that class from any of your Activities. That way you are using dialog's properly as well as making it reusable.

Comment: Good idea. I put the AsyncTask in a separate class that gets instantiated. The Dialog gets created on the Activity Context that I pass into the new class.